# Pandas - Appending 'table' format to HDF5Store with different dtypes: invalid combinate of [values_axes]

Tags: python, pandas, append, store, hdf5

I recently started trying to use HDF5 format in python pandas to store data but encountered a problem where cant find a workaround for. Before i worked with CSV files and i had no trouble in regards to appending new data.

This is what i try:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('cdw.h5')
frame.to_hdf('cdw.h5','cdw/data_cleaned', format='table',append=True, data_columns=True,dropna=False)
```

And it throws:

```
ValueError: invalid combinate of [values_axes] on appending data [name->Ordereingangsdatum,cname->Ordereingangsdatum,dtype->float64,kind->float,shape->(1, 176345)] vs current table [name->Ordereingangsdatum,cname->Ordereingangsdatum,dtype->bytes128,kind->string,shape->None]
```

I get that it tells me i want to append different data type for a column but what buffles me is that i have wrote the same CSV file before with some other CSV Files from a Dataframe to that HDF5 file.

I'm doing analysis in the forwarding industry and the data there is very inconsistent - more often than not there are missing values or mixed dtypes in columns or other 'data dirt'.

Im looking for a way to append data to HDF5 file no matter what is inside the column as long as the column names are the same.

It would be beautiful to enforce appending data in HDF store independant of datatypes or another simple solution for my problem. The goal is to have an automation later on for the analysis therefore id not like to change datatypes everytime i have a missing value in a column of the total 62 columns i have.

Another question in my question is:

My file access for `read_hdf` consumes more time than my `read_csv` i have around 1.5 million rows with 62 columns. Is this because i have no SSD drive? Because i have read that the file access for `read_hdf` should be faster.

I question myself if I rather should stick with CSV files or with HDF5?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it still dont work even when changing from `data_columns=True` to  `data_columns=['ID']`. What I'am looking for is simply a reliable append method that either uses the datatypes given in the hdf5 file or dont check them at all when appending. All i could find was "rebuilding" the table: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818327/how-to-effiiciently-rebuild-pandas-hdfstore-table-when-append-fails). But i could not understand what the code really does as im pretty new to python. I will stick with CSV Files for my Datawarehouse for now if there is no other solution.

Comment: Update: I tried to convert all my columns to object type so that `df.to_hdf` should not have any business checking for integer or float - oh boy i was wrong...
`TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [Volumen_M] because
its data contents are [mixed] object dtype`

 pretty stubborn this hdf5 appending from pandas. I'd say if data always comes perfectly with given data types and never had any missing value or mixed data types then HDF5 would have been a good storage format. Too bad reality isnt like this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay for anyone having the same issue with appending data where the dtype is not always secured to be the same: I finally found a solution. First convert every column to object with `li = list(frame)
frame[li] = frame[li].astype(object)
frame.info()` then try the method `df.to_hdf(key,value, append=True)` and wait for its error message. The error message `TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [not_one_datatype] because its data contents are [mixed] object dtype` will tell the columns it still doesnt like. Converting those columns to float worked for me! After that the error convert the mentioned column with `df['not_one_datatype'].astype(float)` only use `integer` if you are sure that a float will never occur in this column otherwise append method will bug again.

I decided to work parallel with CSV and HDF5 Files. If i get a problem with HDF5 where i have no workaround for i will simply change to CSV - this is what i can recommend personally.

Update: Okay it seems that the creators of this format have not thought about the reality when considering the HDF API: `HDF5 min_itemsize error: ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [##] in [y] column but this column has a limit of [##]!` occurs when trying to append data to an already existing file if some column happens to be longer than the initial write to HDF file.

Now the joke here is that the creators of this API expecting me to know the max column length of each possible data in a column at the first write? really? Another inconsistency is that `df.to_hdf(append=True)` do not have the parameter `min_itemsize={'column1':1000}`. This format is at best suited for storing self created data only but definately not for data where the dtypes and length of the entries in each column are NOT set in stone. The only solution left when you want to append data from pandas dataframes independent of the stubborn HDF5 API in Python is to insert in every dataframe before appending a row with very long strings except for the numeric columns. Just to be sure that you will always  be able to append the data no matter how possible long it will get.

When doing this write process will take ages and slurp gigantic sizes of disc drive for saving the huge HDF5 file.

CSV definately wins against HDF5 in terms of performance, integration and especially **usability**.

Comment: I believe the indexing of the table in hdf5 is the source of the max. length requirement in hdf5. (Just a note to give a more nuanced view, as I believe the creators of hdf5 were not blind eyed for reality.)

Comment: My experience is that HDF is best with numeric data.  Having lots of strings generally gives me the same pains you are experiencing.
I recently got the mixed type error for cols that where mostly numbers but sometimes not.  I coverted all the object types to strings (so the numbers got converted) and things went smoothly.

`obj_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
for c in obj_cols:
    df[c] = df[c].astype('str')`